# RTP Streaming with VLC and remote control

Tags: ssh, streaming, video

I'd like to set up a remotely controlled (through SSH) streaming server with VideoLAN VLC.

I managed start the RTP stream through SSH with the command:

```
cvlc v4l2:///dev/video0 --sout #transcode{vcodec=mp2v,"vb=800,scale=1,acodec=none}:rtp{dst=127.0.0.1,port=5004,mux=ts}" 
            :no-sout-rtp-sap :no-sout-standard-sap :ttl=1 :sout-keep
```

But I don't know how to send PAUSE/PLAY/EXIT commands through SSH. I suppose a way to terminate the VLC process could suffice. How can I do that?

I'm using Java and GanymedSSH for the remote shell.